# Can I derive IV, if I know Encrypted Txt, Key and Encryption Method?

Tags: aes, cryptanalysis, block-cipher, sha-256, decryption

I want to know is there any way to derive the initialization vector, if I know all the other details.

AES SHA 256bits
CBC pkcs5padding

Input: Hello

Key: 123

Output: xORGCDL88sa8cUrK8JNSCQ==

Now, how to find IV?

Comment: Does the padding oracle attack is possible? If not, no! CBC mode is CPA secure.

Comment: @kelalaka: CBC mode is not CPA secure if the adversary knows the key

Comment: @poncho uh, The key is known. Forget security. The question is much easier than. use the libraries..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know is there any way to derive the initialization vector, if I know all the other details.

Well, the first block (16 bytes for AES) of CBC mode encryption is defined as:

$$C_0 = E_k( IV \oplus P_0 )$$

where $P_0$ is the first block of the padded plaintext, and $C_0$ is the first block of the ciphertext.

If you know $C_0, P_0, k$, then you can rearrange this into:

$$IV = P_0 \oplus D_k( C_0 )$$

where $D_k$ is the AES transform in decryption mode, based on key $k$.

This allows you to rederive the IV directly.

Comment: Nitpick, there should be one block with `hello`.

Comment: @kelalaka: that's why I said that $P_0$ is the first block of the **padded** plaintext; that is, the `hello` after padding is added